# Javascript Obtener los checkbox checked de una Datatable creada por Ajax, en todas las páginas

Tags: javascript, ajax, checkbox

Tengo un problema. Relleno una tabla Datatable por Ajax y recibe varias columnas, una de ellas es un Checkbox y algunos estan Checked (marcados) pero en varias paginas (Uso paginación de 10 filas).

Uso esto en JS para obtener los Checked, pero solo reconoce los que estan marcados cuando me dirijo manualmente a cada página donde estan los Checkbox marcados, es decir si son 50 páginas, y hay un checkbox marcado en la página 42, tengo que ir hasta allá manualmente para que los reconozca. Uso estas instrucciones:

```
    var data = table.rows(function(idx, data, node) {
        return $(node).find('input[type="checkbox"][name="activo[]"]').prop('checked');
    }).data().toArray();
```

Este es mi php donde envío la respuesta a la petición de Ajax:

```
 $sub_array[] = "<input type='checkbox' id='activo' name='activo[]' onclick='check_clientes()' checked='checked'>";
```

Necesito leer todos los checkbox marcados despues de cargar la tabla obtenida por Ajax.
Alguna recomendación? Gracias por su ayuda... soy novato en esto.